# How can I make the 500.ejs page appear for all server errors?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

How can I can make 500.ejs page appear across server failures, not only when I run "res.serverError (err);".

I appreciate the help you provide me, I've searched on the official documentation and can not find anything useful.

Comment: Can you give an example of a time you'd like the 500.ejs to be displayed where it currently does not?

Comment: @ScottGress ofcourse look at the screenshot: http://imgur.com/bLeu3P5

Comment: It looks like the view-rendering code in Sails was actually not using the res.serverError; I've [pushed a fix](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/commit/fc2284573122d7a5417954c5d3e6117a0b5c088f) to the master branch.  Were there any other places where you saw the default 500 page not being displayed?